# CSS hover no text margin/padding

Tags: css

I added a hover effect to a navigation, sadly the hover is also effecting the text on it. How could i add a hover to the navigation without effecting the text position?

I can't find a way around this sadly.

Html template: http://projects.helpful.ninja/BlackzDesignz/Template_example/

CSS file: http://projects.helpful.ninja/BlackzDesignz/Template_example/assets/css/style.css

CSS code related to navbar:

```
ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

li{
    list-style: none; 
}

.navbar_item{
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    width:10%;
}

.navbar_item:hover{
    color: #1a1a1a;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url("../images/navbar_hover.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#navbar_home{
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: #ffed00;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #212121;
}
```

Does anyone have a idea?

Comment: can you share some light on the css code you made ?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in this css class, you should remove

```
 margin-top: 3px; 

.navbar_item:hover{
 color: #1a1a1a;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-image: url("../images/navbar_hover.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 font-weight: bold;
! margin-top: 3px; ! //remove this line
```

}

now offcourse with every **hover** it will margin the text with 3px. If you remove this it will be solved

Answer (score 0):

You applied `margin-top: 3px; in .navbar_item:hover` which is pushing down li by 3px when hovering, apply 3px in normal state if you need 3px margin-top. Don't use different values from normal states in margin/padding for hover/focus/active.
For example if you have `.navbar-item {margin-top: 3px;}` and if you apply `.navbar-item:hover {margin-top: 5px;}` it will flicker the text or change the position of texts as yours.